# mounting share on Mojave says No such file or directory

Tags: macos, mount, windows-server-2008-r2, macos-mojave

I am trying to mount a share on Mojave 10.14.3 for Mac mini distribution point hosted on VM Windows Server 2008 R2 using the following command :

```
mount_smbfs -f 0755 -d 0755 smb://username:pwd@ip_address/Users/Shared/ /Volumes/Guest
```

It throws the following error :

```
mount_smbfs: mount error: /Volumes/guest: No such file or directory
```

I have created the directory. If I try to create again it says directory exists.

Comment: I'm seeing this too - on macOS 11.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on the commands you show above, your problem looks like you try to mount on `Guest` but you have created `guest`. Since macOS High Sierra (10.13), the default file system (APFS) is case-sensitive. Thus, you need to use the same capitalization when referring to the mount point in your commands.

Note also that the protocol isn't part of the location specification in the command. Take a look at the [`man` page for `mount_smbfs`](http://web.archive.org/web/20150923111025/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html) for more information and examples. Note also that the `man` page recommends using `mount` instead of calling `mount_smbfs` directly:

```
mkdir -p /Volumes/guest
mount -t smbfs -o -f=0755,-d=0755 //username:pwd@ip_address/Users/Shared/ /Volumes/guest
```

Comment: I tried using the commands suggested by you. Still same error.     mount_smbfs: mount error: /Volumes/guest: No such file or directory

Comment: @ksimpi were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by putting the last argument (i.e the mounting point) in quotes. So in OP case, it would be:

```
mount_smbfs -f 0755 -d 0755 smb://username:pwd@ip_address/Users/Shared/ "/Volumes/Guest"
```